# PHP: Redundant check for empty array/collection?

Tags: php, laravel

I inherited a Laravel project and I'm still working my way through learning it.  I see in the code there is a check to run a block only if the `$patient->records` is there but check for it is:

`if(! empty($patient->records) && $patient->records->count() > 0)`

is that redundant or is empty and count() checking 2 separate things?

EDIT: corrected from `> 1` to `> 0`

Comment: That should be producing a syntax error.

Comment: interesting..why is that?

Comment: Unless Laravel is doing something screwy, PHP does not use dot-notation.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Probably not a syntax error, that's just interpreted as a concatenation.

Comment: At any rate, you should read the docs to understand `empty()`: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Comment: My apologies.  I'm still in a Ruby frame of mind -- I copied it over wrong.  It's `->count()`

Comment: It depends on the relationship. If it's a `hasOne` `$patient->records` could be null. In that case, omitting the empty check would result in an error calling method `count` on null.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's redundant. $patient->records is a collection.
I use like this.

```
if($patient->records->count()) 
{
// has records
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend `if($patient->records->isNotEmpty()) { ... }` as it is the most readable solution and does not involve implicit casting of int to bool for the if.

Comment: Depends on how the $patient is created.  in some instances $patient->records could be `null` and not a collection, and thus the check for isset() or !empty might be needed and not redundant at all.

Comment: @J.A.Streich If `records` is a relation that can have multiple related models (hasMany, BelongsToMany, etc) then it will **always** be a collection, even if there aren't any related records. If `$patient` is created in a way that the records relation isn't available then it is a problem with that variable and not related to this question.

Comment: Not in all versions.  I've had relationships return `null` in Laravel 5.2.  Anything 5.4 and above, I've not seen it happen.

Comment: You can always use `if(optional($patient->records)->isNotEmpty()) { ... }` if you want to make it `null` safe. :)

Comment: Or just check for null, like the parent suggested, and not add another function activation record to the stack.  Because `optional()` just calls the same system functions we'd be using.

Comment: That's of course true, but in this case the stack is popped right after `isNotEmpty()`. So it isn't much of an issue and more a question of taste I guess.

Comment: @J.A.Streich I just checked out a fresh version of 5.2 and set up a test relation for both hasMany, and belongsToMany. Both returned an empty collection. I suspect your relations weren't set up properly, not the framework being inconsistent.

Comment: It's old code and works ;) ....  Just checked the project I was thinking about, and the use case is different than I remember.  It is in the form partial blade.  Which is used in both create and edit, where the original model may or may not be defined.  So the checks are to see if the fields (relations) exists are really checking if the object itself is really defined or not.

Comment: I believe isNotEmpty is better becose laravel make a verification if the array inside the collection is not empty (!empty($this->items))... the empty php function return false for null, empty string, empty array, 0, '0'... and so on.... Doesnt matter if the variable is a collection, array or null ...  https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Answer (score 1):

If there is a possibility that $patient or records (assumed to be a property of $patient) can be undefined, then the `empty($patient->records)` is helpful because $patient->records->count() by itself would result in a fatal error: 
`Uncaught Error: Call to a member function count() on null in ...`

With `empty($patient->records)` in the if clause, that fatal error can be avoided, even in the case that $patient or records is undefined.

The empty is checking that $patient->records is defined and not empty, while the count() part of the clause is a more specific check on the result of the count method. That method is not available in the case where $patient or records is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, it is redundant.**

**Then, why someone can possible have written the code this way?**

May be, before checking the length of the collection he wanted to make sure that it's not `null` though I prefer using `is_null()` or `isset()` method instead in such case. Even if that(null safe) was in his mind, still it's unnecessary. Because if the relationship between `patient` and `records` defined correctly(one to many => `hasMany()`) then `$patient->records` will always return a collection but never null. Even if it's an empty collection you can still use `count()` method safely without even checking if the `records` is null or not because it's never going to be null if we return a `hasMany()` relation.

**What could be a better solution**

You can just use this same condition removing the empty checking part as below:

`if($patient->records->count() > 0)`

To make it more readable, Laravel collection is offering us a very nice method called `isNotEmpty()`:

`if($patient->records->isNotEmpty())`

This is what I prefer to use. Because we write code to make it readable to other programmer/us, not for computer. Computer can even understand binary but we don't write binary.